# Finding the shortest path to a node in an undirected graph

Tags: nodes, dijkstra, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, path-finding

so rather than just posting my question with the hopes of someone to solve it, I would just like to receive some insight on what I need to do next. So, the situation is as such. I have a set of integers in the format of:

11   3
2    3
0    3
x    x
x    x

Those integers are represented as nodes, where the 11 connects to the 3, 2 to the 3, and so on. My aim is to create a path that will show how to reach from going to point 0 to point 1 using any means of algorithms. My first attempt has gotten me to use Dijikstra's algorithm, with the following showing my attempt at the coding:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
 {
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
         return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
     public final Vertex target;
     public final double weight;
     public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
     { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
 }

  class Dijkstra
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
        if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
            vertexQueue.remove(v);

            v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
            v.previous = u;
            vertexQueue.add(v);
        }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // mark all the vertices 
    Vertex A = new Vertex("0");
    Vertex B = new Vertex("1");
    Vertex C = new Vertex("2");
    Vertex D = new Vertex("3");
    Vertex E = new Vertex("4");
    Vertex F = new Vertex("5");
    Vertex G = new Vertex("6");
    Vertex H = new Vertex("7");
    Vertex I = new Vertex("8");
    Vertex J = new Vertex("9");
    Vertex K = new Vertex("10");
    Vertex L = new Vertex("11");


    // set the edges and weight
    A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 1) };
    A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(F, 1) };
    B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(E, 1) };
 //   C.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 1) };
 //   D.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A, 1) };
    D.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C, 1) };
    D.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(L, 1) };
    E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 1) };
 //   E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(F, 1) };
 //   F.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A, 1) };
    F.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(E, 1) };
    F.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(H, 1) };
 //   G.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(H, 1) };
 //   H.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(F, 1) };
    H.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(G, 1) };
    H.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(I, 1) };
 //   I.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(H, 1) };
    I.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(J, 1) };
 //   J.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(I, 1) };
    J.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(K, 1) };
 //   K.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(J, 1) };
 //   L.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 1) };



    computePaths(A); // run Dijkstra
    System.out.println("Distance to " + B + ": " + B.minDistance);
    List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(B);
    System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
}
```

Again, the aim is to get from 0 to 1. The quickest path is going to be from going to node 0 > 5 > 4 > 1, or (A > F > E > B) but I cannot figure out how to get the system to make this work. Any help in regards to this would be much appreciated!

Regards,

Your everyday nerd in need of help!

P.S. this is the error code I am receiving :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Dijkstra.computePaths(name.java:42)
    at Dijkstra.main(name.java:111)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some standard methods.

Method A: You record all points that you could possibly reach and their distance. You start with the start point at a distance 0. For each point you find which neighbours it has, in order of distance from nearest to farthest.

You then add a new point: The point that you add is a point that you haven't added yet with the closest distance to the starting point. You would go from any reachable point to its nearest neighbour that isn't in your list yet. And out of all the possibilities you take the point that is closest to your starting point (for an efficient calculation you use priority list. If you went from X to Y, adding Y, you change X in the priority list so you go the next-nearest neighbour that it has, or remove it completely if all its neighbours have been added. And you add Y with its nearest neighbour that hasn't been added yet).

The calculation ends when you added the end point.

If you look at a street map, this algorithm has the problem that it doesn't actually try to get to the goal. If start and end point are 100 miles apart, it will try all points in a 100 mile radius around the start, roughly. If the distance data is suitable, you replace every distance (X, Y) with the distance (X, Y), minus the amount that you get closer to your goal by going from X to Y. The search will be much quicker because now it prefers points along the line from start to end. If the triangular equation holds, and there is a direct line from start to end, the algorithm will now *immediately* pick that direct line.